# Running mysql in the foreground in centos

Tags: mysql, centos, docker

I am building a docker image for a mysql database. For that purpose, I have to run mysql in the foreground and not as a deamon service. I am using a centos base image. How to run mysql in the foreground?

Comment: Lots of examples on github. https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-mysql

Comment: just use this: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run `mysqld_safe`

```
CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

The process should be in the foreground and blocking.

However as the comments above suggest, there are several official supported MySQL containers which you should consider using.