# What are potential negative side effects of running a cronjob every few minutes to start mysqld?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have an issue with the mysql server on one of my physical webservers. It crashes periodically ( every few to tens of days or so ). I have been unable to trace the issue. The site does not need to be up every second, so being down for a few minutes once a week is not an issue.

In lieu of continuing to chase this issue, I can run a cronjob that attempts to start mysql every minute. When it goes down, it'll come back up 60 seconds later.

```
*/1 * * * * /sbin/service mysqld start
```

What are potential negative side effects of this solution ( besides it being super lame that I'm not chasing the root cause ... I've got more important things to do ).

Comment: not sure about daemon processes, but can it start like 3600 instances of mysqld a day?  that could become a problem if it does...

Comment: The correct solution wold be to solve the actual problem. *Why* does it crash? Does it need upgrading? Reinstalling? Corrupt files?

Comment: Some mysql restarting tips here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35395/is-there-a-graceful-or-safe-restart-for-mysql-like-for-apache-httpd

Comment: *I've got more important things to do* ...perhaps, until you lose some data.  MySQL should not be crashing, and uncovering the cause should not be an impossible task.  Highly likely, a shortage of memory (particularly if you are running Apache) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/mysql-innodb-crash-post-mortem and it's not really crashing - the system is killing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with another demon (`vpnc`)that would keep falling over so what I did was start it in non-demon mode in a loop:

```
while true
do
        demon-process-foreground
        sleep 1
done
```

The `sleep 1` is optional.  As to running MySQL in the foreground have a look at
[Running mysql in the foreground in centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563762/running-mysql-in-the-foreground-in-centos)